# Is it possible to add new elements to the Spring DSL?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I’m trying to add some new functionality to Camel - essentially a custom processor which takes several parameters and performs certain data manipulation, as well as the global configuration for all processors of this type within a given camel context. My challenge is that I would like to have both Java and XML DSLs supported, i.e. instead of having to define Spring beans and then using Camel’s `<custom>` tags, I would prefer having a custom namespaces and meaningful element names, e.g.:

```
<acme:my-global-config com=“foo”/>

<route>
    <from uri=“direct:doSomething”/>
    <acme:my-custom-processor param=“value” param2=“value2”/>
    <to uri=“direct:doSomethingElse”/>
</route>
```

Is it possible to do it in Camel?

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible. Extending the DSL in XML is difficult and its not something that is on the roadmap.